My Javascripting skills are pretty much non-existent. How can I do something like this curl example in a browser with javascript?
The cik should be a variable I would need to increment "from" to allow pagination.
curl -XPOST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{
  "query": "cik:<CIK_VALUE_FROM_USER> AND formType:\"4\"",
  "from": "0",
  "size": "10",
  "sort": [{ "filedAt": { "order": "desc" } }]
}' 'https://api.sec-api.io?token=<MY_CONSTANT_TOKEN_VALUE>'

This is the stupid crap I've tried so far. "<>" have replaced the variable and a token I got from the SEC.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Insider Trading</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    const userAction = async () => {
      var queryBody = {
        "query": "cik:<CIK_VAR_FROM_USER> AND formType:\"4\"",
        "from": "0",
        "size": "1",
        "sort": [{ "filedAt": { "order": "desc" } }]
      }
      const response = await fetch('https://api.sec-api.io?token=<MY_TOKEN>', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: queryBody.toString(), // string or object
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
      });
      const myJson = await response.json(); //extract JSON from the http response
      alert(response.statusText);
    }
  </script>
  <form>
    <button id="form-submit" onclick="userAction()">Submit</button>
    <label>CIK:</label>
    <input type="text" name="cik" placeholder="CIK"></input>
  </form>
  <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>


"This is the stupid crap I've tried so far." - This tells us nothing about the problem you have encountered.  Please update the question to indicate in what way your code is not working as expected and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

try something like (part of the var queryBody):
const queryBody = {
        "query": `cik:${document.querySelector("input[name=cik]").value} AND formType:"4"`,
        "from": from.toString(),
        "size": "1",
        "sort": [{ "filedAt": { "order": "desc" } }]
}

(part at the start of <script>):
let from = 0;

(part after the fetch() call):
from += <how much you want to increment from>;

Explanation: in the "query" I have replaced the " with ` so I can use ${} to insert values in there. Then I used document.querySelector("input[name=cik]") to get the element and used .value to get what's inside the input element. I have also created a variable called from and used it in the from field with .toString() to turn the integer into a string. Also please don't use var for variables as it will be at the top of the parent scope and only declared where you used var, eslint also doesn't like that and it's just confusing. Instead use let or const for constants (I have changed your queryBody to a const).
Full code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Insider Trading</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    let from = 0;
    const userAction = async () => {
        const queryBody = {
            "query": `cik:${document.querySelector("input[name=cik]").value} AND formType:"4"`,
            "from": from.toString(),
            "size": "1",
            "sort": [{ "filedAt": { "order": "desc" } }]
        }
        const response = await fetch('https://api.sec-api.io?token=<MY_TOKEN>', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: queryBody.toString(), // string or object
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });
        const myJson = await response.json(); //extract JSON from the http response
        // alert(response.statusText);
        console.log(response.statusText) // you might not want to use alert
        from += <some number>;
    }</script>
<form>
    <button id="form-submit" onclick="userAction()">Submit</button>
    <label>CIK:</label>
        <input type="text" name="cik" placeholder="CIK"></input>
</form>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>

BTW: Please don't put API keys into the frontend and good luck learning javascript.
